# data.forEach is not a function when trying to get data from an object

Tags: javascript

I am building a search movie web app using web API. My *baseurl* is the web api link. The error I'm getting is ''data.forEach is not a function''. I'm failing to see what is wrong with my code, if you could help would be great.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', baseUrl+searchInput.value, true)

request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        data.forEach(user => {
            console.log(user.Title)
        })
    }
}

request.send();

}
```

Comment: your data variable should be an array Currently it's something else, perhaps an object {}

Comment: What do you see after you do `console.log(data)` after `JSON.parse(this.response)`?

Comment: Console.log data after parsing. It should be an array

Comment: My data is an object and that's why it's not working. I've tried to switch to an array using object key, entries and values but it's mixing my data information.

Is there any other way to do this other than having to convert to an array?

Comment: you should not be converting to an array, rather have your backend resolve with an array. Please update your code with Object.keys to see what can be done from there...

Answer (score 1):

If it's an object, then you can do this:

```js
const obj = {name: "Joe", pass: "tiger123"}

for (let i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i])
}
```

The `for-in` loop can slow down the Javascript compiler though, so a better option might be:

```js
const obj = {name: "Joe", pass: "tiger123"}
const wholeItem = Object.entries(obj)

wholeItem.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i)
})

//OR

const values = Object.values(obj)

values.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i)
})
```